# Compare user-inputted string/character to another string/character

Tags: string, assembly, arm, string-comparison

So I'm a bit of a beginner to ARM Assembly (assembly in general, too).  Right now I'm writing a program and one of the biggest parts of it is that the user will need to type in a letter, and then I will compare that letter to some other pre-inputted letter to see if the user typed the same thing.

For instance, in my code I have

```
.balign 4 /* Forces the next data declaration to be on a 4 byte segment */
dime: .asciz "D\n"
```

at the top of the file and

```
addr_dime               : .word dime
```

at the bottom of the file.

Also, based on what I've been reading online I put

```
.balign 4
inputChoice: .asciz "%d"
```

at the top of the file, and put

```
inputVal                : .word 0
```

at the bottom of the file.

Near the middle of the file (just trust me that there is something wrong with this standalone code, and the rest of the file doesn't matter in this context) I have this block of code:

```
ldr r3, addr_dime
ldr r2, addr_inputChoice
cmp r2, r3                  /*See if the user entered D*/
addeq r5, r5, #10           /*add 10 to the total if so*/
```

Which I THINK should load "D" into r3, load whatever String or character the user inputted into r2, and then add 10 to r5 if they are the same.

For some reason this doesn't work, and the r5, r5, #10 code only works if addne comes before it.

Answer (score 0):

`addr_dime  : .word dime` is  poitlessly over-complicated.  The address is already a link-time constant.  Storing the address in memory (at another location which has its own address) doesn't help you at all, it just adds another layer of indirection.  (Which is actually the source of your problem.)

Anyway, `cmp` doesn't dereference its register operands, so you're comparing pointers.  If you single-step with a debugger, you'll see that the values in registers are pointers.

To load the single byte at `dime`, zero-extended into r3, do

```
ldrb r3, dime
```

Using `ldr` to do a 32-bit load would also get the `\n` byte, and a 32-bit comparison would have to match that too for `eq` to be true.

But this can only work if `dime` is close enough for a PC-relative addressing mode to fit; like most RISC machines, ARM can't use arbitrary absolute addresses because the instruction-width is fixed.

For the constant, the easiest way to avoid that is *not* to store it in memory in the first place.  Use `.equ dime, 'D'` to define a numeric constant, then you can use

```
cmp r2, dime      @ compare with immediate operand
```

Or  `ldr r3, =dime`  to ask the assembler to get the constant into a register for you.  You can do this with addresses, so you could do

```
ldr   r2, =inputVal     @ r2 = &inputVal
ldrb  r2, [r2]          @ load first byte of inputVal
```

This is the generic way to handle loading from static data that might be too far away for a PC-relative addressing mode.

You could avoid that by using a stack address (`sub sp, #16` / `mov r5, sp` or something).  Then you already have the address in a register.

---

This is exactly what a C compiler does:

```
char dime[4] = "D\n";
char input[4] = "xyz";

int foo(int start) {
    if (dime[0] == input[0])
        start += 10;
    return start;
}
```

From ARM32 gcc6.3 on the [Godbolt compiler explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,source:'char+dime%5B4%5D+%3D+%22D%5Cn%22%3B%0Achar+input%5B4%5D+%3D+%22xyz%22%3B%0A%0Aint+foo(int+start)+%7B%0A++++if+(dime%5B0%5D+%3D%3D+input%5B0%5D)%0A++++++++start+%2B%3D+10%3B%0A++++return+start%3B%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:51.41535396579329,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:armg630,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'1',trim:'1'),libs:!(),options:'-xc+-Wall+-O3+-marm',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'ARM+gcc+6.3.0+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)',t:'0')),k:48.58464603420673,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4):

```
foo:
        ldr     r3, .L4         @ load a pointer to the data section at dime / input
        ldrb    r2, [r3]
        ldrb    r3, [r3, #4]
        cmp     r2, r3
        addeq   r0, r0, #10
        bx      lr
.L4:
        @ gcc greated this "literal pool" next to the code
        @ holding a pointer it can use to access the data section,
        @ wherever the linker ends up putting it.
        .word   .LANCHOR0

.section .data
.p2align  2
 @@@ These are in a different section, near each other.
 @@@ On Godbolt, click the .text button to see full assembler directives.

.LANCHOR0:      @  actually defined with a .set directive, but same difference.
dime:
        .ascii  "D\012\000"
input:
        .ascii  "xyz\000"
```

Try changing the C to compare with a literal character instead of a global the compiler can't optimize into a constant, and see what you get.

Comment: When I do that I get an error that says internal_relocation(type: OFFSET_IMM) not fixed up

Comment: @PCRevolt: Ah, yeah I wondered if the assembler would magically take care of using an addressing-mode that could reach the data.  ARM uses fixed-width instructions, and they don't have room for an arbitrary 32-bit absolute address.  There is a PC-relative addressing mode with small offsets, so ARM code often uses a "literal pool" to load data from a block near the actual code.  See what a C compiler does: https://godbolt.org/g/xnRrNa. You could avoid this if you just used stack memory for your buffers, instead of static.  So you just get the address in a pointer and `ldrb r3, [r5]`.

Comment: But what would r5 be in this scenario

Comment: @PCRevolt: I was thinking `mov r5, sp` after reserving some space on the stack, and passing that pointer to scanf or read, as the destination for user input.  But see my updated answer.

Comment: How would I reserve space on a stack?  I'm reallllly new to this.  Not sure what a literal pool is.

Comment: A "literal pool" is constants in memory stored near the instructions, in range of a PC-relative addressing mode.  My updated answer describes how to reserve space on the stack.  Google either of those terms for much more info.

Comment: What is .Lanchoro

Comment: @PCRevolt: Thats a zero, not an `o`.  Updated the code to show that part of gcc's output, too.  It's all there in gcc's output on godbolt if you turn off filtering out directives.